# Make if elif else to move onto next elif

Tags: python, if-statement

Suppose there is this code

```
statement = input()

if "book" not in statement:
    if "what" in statement:
        print("something")
    # else: 
        # something here which will make the program to move onto the next elif
    
elif "bag" in statement:
    print("anything")
elif "book" in statement:
    print("everything")
```

now if we execute the code, and there's no `"book"` in `statement` but there is `"bag"` it won't print anything. I know I can add `and` in the first condition but my real code is more complicated.
Please tell me a way so that it will move on to the next `elif`, if "what" is not in `statement`

Comment: @PeterWood Then it would trigger regardless of the inner if.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes here. This question seems sufficiently detailed and clear.  It also at this point has a clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is not possible in general. In your particular case, you can restructure the first condition to achieve the desired behaviour (as you have stated yourself):

```
if "book" not in statement and "what" in statement:
    print("something")
elif "bag" in statement:
    print("anything")
elif "book" in statement:
    print("everything"
```

For the more complex case, you would have to use a workaround by setting some flag:

```
_else = True
if "book" not in statement:
    if "what" in statement:
        print("something")
        _else = False
    else: 
        # lots of spaghetti code
if _else: 
    if "bag" in statement:
        print("anything")
    elif "book" in statement:
        print("everything")
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving to the next `elif` even when the premise is true goes against what control structures are meant for.

You could achieve that by using just `if` but it's not clear if that solves your problem.